# Icon font horizontal alignment issue following window size

Tags: html, css, alignment, icon-fonts

I used Fontastic to create an Icon Font.
My problem is:

When page width is odd, the image miss aligned to the red circle.

When page width is even, the image is aligned to the red circle.

[image]

Here is the div itself

[image]

And its pseudo element declaration ::before

[image]

I guess that it's a pixel/browser/device issue, the font must be aligned to the pixel grid while images and browser rendered styles can be blurred to be stradding pixels?
Is there a way to fixe it? Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you considered using (possibly inline) SVG icons instead of an icon font?

Comment: Please post actual code, not images of code. Thanks